# Making a new list by modifying an existing list in R

Tags: r, list

I'd like to make a new list by modifying an existing list of strings. For an element in the list, eg `..0..fishgold..1..2`, I'd like to extract the digits (`0`, `1`, `2`), and make a new list in which the string is assigned the values of the extracted digits (`"..0..fishgold..1..2" = 0`, `"..0..fishgold..1..2" = 1`, `"..0..fishgold..1..2" = 2`).

I've made a couple of attempts, see below code, but I can't get my desired result (`goal_list`).

```
# Load packages 
library(stringr)

# Load toy data 
df = data.frame("dog..0..brown..1.."=c(1,0,1,7,NA), "cat..0..grey..1..2"=c(5,0,2,1,NA), "..0..fishgold..1..2"=c(1,NA,2,9,NA))

# Existing list
my_list = as.list(colnames(df))


# Attempt 1 function for making new list
my_function = function(old_elem, new_elem){
  new_elem = paste(old_elem, "=", str_extract_all(old_elem, "[:digit:]+"))
  print(new_elem)
}


# Attempt 2 function for making new list
my_function = function(old_elem){
  assign(old_elem, str_extract_all(old_elem, "[:digit:]+"))
  print(old_elem)
}


# New list
new_list= as.list(lapply(my_list, my_function))

# Desired new list 
goal_list = list("dog..0..brown..1.." = 0,
              "dog..0..brown..1.." = 1,
              "cat..0..grey..1..2" = 0,
              "cat..0..grey..1..2" = 1,
              "cat..0..grey..1..2" = 2,
              "..0..fishgold..1..2" = 0,
              "..0..fishgold..1..2" = 1,
              "..0..fishgold..1..2" = 2)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear whether the input should be the `my_list`.  If the intention is to loop over the `list` (instead of `unlist`ing), then use `map`, apply the `str_extract_all` (it can be directly applied on the `vector`), `enframe` into a two column tibble, `unnest` the 'value' column, convert it to `integer` (as `str_extract_all` returns a `list` of strings, `deframe` the data.frame to a named `vector`, and convert it to `list`

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- map_df(my_list, ~ set_names(str_extract_all(.x, "\\d+"), .x)  %>% 
            enframe %>%        
            unnest(value)  %>%
            mutate(value = as.integer(value))) %>%
       deframe %>% 
       as.list
all.equal(out, goal_list)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or in another way, use `str_count` to get the number of digits in the name, `rep`licate the `names` of the data.frame based on that, extract the digits from the `names` with `str_extract_all`, set its names with the replicated names, and convert the `vector` to a `list` with `as.list`

```
as.list(setNames(as.integer(unlist(str_extract_all(names(df), "\\d+"))), 
              rep(names(df), str_count(names(df), "\\d+"))))
```

---

Or using only `base R`

```
l1 <- regmatches(names(df), gregexpr("\\d+", names(df)))
as.list(with(transform(stack(setNames(l1, names(df))), 
      values = as.integer(values)), setNames(values, ind)))
```

NOTE: `assign` is not needed here as it is to assign values to an identifier object